# Change Kestrel port at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, port, kestrel

My project uses .net core 3.1 and is a web app using builtin server Kestrel.
I setup the ports using .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:1234") during CreateWebHostBuilder() and works as it should.

In my interface I wanted the user to able to change port at runtime.
But I have to restart the application with the new saved config to get that working.
Are there any tips on how to change it at runtime?

Comment: It's impossible, the port attribute indicates the port number on which the server is communicating. You can't modify it at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved (quick and dirty) the restart-server function for Kestrel.
This method is just a hack and should not be used in production. Maybe there are some clever heads out there who can make it better.

```cs
public class Program
{
    //Simple bool to tell the host to load again
    public static bool RestartWebserver { get; set; } = false;
    
    //Port to use
    public static int HttpPort { get; set; } = 80;

    //Main program
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Infinityloop if 
        while(true)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Build().Run();
            
            //If RestartWebserver is false, exit everything...
            if (!RestartWebserver)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Restarting...");
                break;
            }
            
            //Reset for the "new" host to be created.
            RestartWebserver = false;
        }
    }

    //Helper for creating host, returns a IWebHostBuilder to be Build and runned.
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args, string ContentRoot)
    {
        var Address = "0.0.0.0";
        string http = "http://" + Address + ":" + HttpPort;

        //Add arguments to the config (we could have a port set here too..)
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddCommandLine(args)
                .Build();
        Startup.Configuration = configuration;

        //Return Webhost
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseContentRoot(ContentRoot)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls(new string[] { http }));
    }
}

//Now in any controller you can force close the host like this
public class RestartController : Controller
{
    public IHostApplicationLifetime _applicationLifetime;
    
    public StatusController(IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        _applicationLifetime = applicationLifetime;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        //Set new port
        Program.HttpPort = 12345;
        
        //Set the server to restart
        Program.RestartWebserver = true;
        
        //Quit current host
        _applicationLifetime.StopApplication();

        //This function will fail.
        //Suggest to create a javascript file to reload client to the new port...
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

This method worked for me, but the code above is kind of sudo, it has never been compiled in its form. Concept though is tested and confirmed on dotnet v5.0.100

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var address = app.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();
    address.Addresses.Clear();
    address.Addresses.Add("http://*:5556");
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement this, but the IApplicationBuilder isn't available in DI other in the "Startup-class". So how could it be possible todo this at runtime?

Comment: Just get HttpContext. You can access Features property on it. Depending on where you want it, it may already be available in base class (like Controller). In your own service you can just register 

services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

and inject IHttpContextAccessor to get to HttpContext

Comment: Strange, I could not get any hit on HttpContext.Features.Get<IApplicationBuilder>(); nor HttpContext.Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>(); in my controller. I though the features functions was limited to these interfaces: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/request-features?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

From ASP.NET Core 5.0 Preview 6 there is an option to react to configuration changes at run time.  More info here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/kestrel-configuration-changes-at-run-time-detected-by-default